# debugging some opengles android game with eclipse encountered outofmemoryerror exception

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, out-of-memory

I'm trying to debug some android opengles soccer game with eclipse(my android device is Dell Streak pad). When the game enters into some match(let's say a worldcup match), the eclipse debugger takes really such a long time, and unfortunately fails with the outofmemoryerror exception.

> Here is the call stack for the crash:
>
> **Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception OutOfMemoryError))**        Bitmap.createBitmap(int, int, Bitmap$Config, boolean) line: 604 
>     Bitmap.createBitmap(int, int, Bitmap$Config) line: 584
>     ActivityThread.createThumbnailBitmap(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord)
>   line: 2442
>     ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   ActivityThread$StopInfo, boolean, boolean) line: 2615 
>     ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(IBinder, boolean, int) line: 2689 
>     ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread, IBinder, boolean, int)
>   line: 122     BinderProxy(ActivityThread$H).handleMessage(Message) line:
>   1038      ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
>     Looper.loop() line: 132     ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4123
>     Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native method]      Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 491      ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 841
>     ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 599     NativeStart.main(String[])
>   line: not available [native method]
>
> **Daemon System Thread [<2> HeapWorker] (Suspended (exception OutOfMemoryError))**        BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize() line: 48
>     NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]
>
> **Thread [<9> GLThread 10] (Suspended (exception OutOfMemoryError))**     GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run() line: 1188

And there is also some info with the logcat:

```
02-25 15:07:33.931: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17453): threadid=2: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-25 15:07:33.931: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17453): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 1% free 48888K/49159K, paused 414ms
02-25 15:07:33.931: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(17453): Out of memory on a 62116-byte allocation.
02-25 15:07:33.931: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17453): threadid=9: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4014b5c8 self=0x125f8
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   | sysTid=17453 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1342909336
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=249 stm=13 core=1
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:604)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:584)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.app.ActivityThread.createThumbnailBitmap(ActivityThread.java:2442)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2615)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:2689)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-25 15:07:33.931: INFO/dalvikvm(17453):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and so on.

I've tried to run it on my android device directly, and things seem to be all right, no crash, and takes acceptable time to load & run. I wonder if it is because the vm heap memory  is not enough, so I've tried to increase vm memory value in eclipse.ini, after that I also closed the eclipse and restarted it:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m

But it doesn't work. Although it runs well on the device, but I need to debug the game match for breakpoints, stepping. Without the debugging, it would be very bad. Anyone who knows sth about this please help me on this.

Note: I am debugging the opengles game on a device(dell streak pad as I mentioned), so there would be no problem with the emulator doesn't support opengles.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator can't do opengl at this time, you can only use a real device for testing opengl apps.

Comment: I'm debugging on my dell streak pad. Even so, I still need eclipse to debug it. It runs well without the eclipse debugging.